# Published article with Inactive DOI

Tags: doi

I submitted a paper to SciTechnol, I paid the article processing charges. The paper is now published on their website with a DOI which is inactive when checking on Crossref metadata and DOI.org  I contacted Crossref why is that, they replied that the publishing website has not paid their subscription fees to Crossref for a year.
Now, my paper is published but not traceable on SciTechnol.
Multiple requests to withdraw the article failed to bring any answers or replies from SciTechnol.
I am considering submitting the paper to another journal. Is that possible?
Is there a way to get this publication DOI active from my side ?
What are the ethical issues here? Can I take this publishing website to court to claim damages?

---

Thanks for the interactive discussion. I must say that I learnt a lot listening to you all.
I did not transfer copyright for this open access as I did not sign documents for that. Would this allow me to submit somewhere else since they turning a deaf ear to my request to withdraw the paper?
Searching the paper title on Google, it does come up (but not when using the DO The reason I wanted the active DOI is that it makes referring to paper easier. SciTechnol insisted that the DOI would be activated once I paid the APC what a cheating trickery.
I now read about this FTC ruling, what a revelation. Had I known about this or Beall's list, I would have looked away at that time.
Shayn from CrossRef emailed me back to answer that SciTechnol did not pay their Crossref subs, he made no reference to FTC ruling.
Now, since I paid with a Visa Card, I started a case dispute via my bank. At least to limit the damages

Comment: Possibly relevant: There is a "SciTechnol" in Beall's list of (potentially) predatory journals, https://beallslist.net/.

Comment: Scitechnol is a publisher, not a journal.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Well, a publisher could be predatory on the whole, or did I get that wrong.

Comment: Did you transfer copyright?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Sure. For instance, Beall's list is a list of publishers, not of journals. This was just a detail that does not invalidate the discussion.

Comment: To play devil's advocate: Why do you _need_ a DOI?  Not having one isn't evidence that the publication doesn't exist, or that it isn't reputable.  Can you not provide a direct link?  Is the paper not discoverable through a Google search for the title?  Or is the paper not online at all?

Answer (score 4):

I just want to clarify that SciTechnol's Crossref membership was not terminated due to their failure to pay their subscription fees.  It was terminated because SciTechnol is a subsidiary of OMICS, and Crossref terminated all OMICS members after the [FTC ruling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMICS_Publishing_Group#FTC_suit) against them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and welcome to this forum! Could you please specify in your answer that you work for Crossref, to clarify this potential conflict of interest situation? I see it is in your username, but usernames can be changed at any time, so it is preferred to include this information in answers.